# Python requests throws "ValueError" for an Invalid Header

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my first post on SO, so please be easy on me.
In this program, I am trying to change userAgents after a certain number of failed attempts. There is a file of ~10000 userAgents located in the UserAgents.txt file, UTF-8 encoded. 
I am writing a program in python that needs to scrape data from a website. I am getting the following error:

> ValueError: Invalid header value b'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36\n'

I realize that the 'b' in front of the string means that it is byte encoded.
The steps that I have followed include:

1. `userAgent = userAgent.encode("UTF-8").decode("UTF-8")`

   `userAgent = str(userAgent)`

   `userAgent = userAgentFile.readlines()[0]`

   `userAgentFile = open("UserAgents.txt", "r", encoding="UTF-8")`

   I have also tried defining the user agent within the definition for the headers.

```
userAgentFile = open("UserAgents.txt", "r")
userAgent = userAgentFile.readline()
userAgentFile.close();

headerList = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.2.149.6 Safari/525.13", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-61be9723-4cd53f9228b4db340a348137"
}

headerList["User-Agent"] = str(userAgent)
#Submit a request to our website, and with our "special" headings.
r = requests.get(f"https://www.reddit.com/r/BreadStapledToTrees/", headers=headerList)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

--Also, I am not actually scraping from r/BreadStapledToTrees...

Comment: The program runs OK with your original `headerList`. Please provide a few lines from your `UserAgents.txt` file.  Why do you need to change user agent?

Comment: I assume the problem is that newline character at the end of the value - you need to strip that off after reading the line from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, there is an newline character at the end of the user agent string, so strip it before sending it to `requests`, by changing line 14 to

```
headerList["User-Agent"] = userAgent.strip()
```